# Android XMPP basic connection

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I'm a little bit new to android I'm trying to build a chat android application
using openfire as a server and smack 4.1.6 libs 
for now I'm trying to make a basic connection I'm following the smack documentation

```
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder conf = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    conf.setUsernameAndPassword("user", "user");
    conf.setResource("android");
    conf.setServiceName("my_ip_adress");
    conf.setHost("my_ip_adress");
    conf.setPort(5222);
    conf.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.ifpossible);


    AbstractXMPPConnection connection=new XMPPTCPConnection(conf.build());
    try {
        Log.e("CONNECTION====>", "try");
        connection.connect();
        Log.e("CONNECTION====>", "success");
        connection.login();
        Log.e("LOGIN====>", "success");
    } catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm getting this on my log

```
  E/CONNECTION====>: try
02-26 17:59:14.995 15119-15145/com.example.firas.simplexmpp W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed: '172.16.50.52:5222' failed because java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /172.16.50.52 (port 5222) after 30000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

these are my dependencies

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.6'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.6'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.6'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.6'
```

Comment: If your client is out of the network of the server you must use the real ip of the server. Also, if your server is behind a NAT you have to open the TCP port (5222)

Answer (score 1):

Check if your phone or emulator has internet connection

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
  = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi in case this 'll help anyone in the future I ve set the ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode to disables and that works fine

```
02-28 11:00:55.651 30656-30682/com.example.firas.simplexmpp E/CONNECTION====>: try
02-28 11:00:55.721 30656-30682/com.example.firas.simplexmpp E/CONNECTION====>: success
02-28 11:00:56.162 30656-30682/com.example.firas.simplexmpp E/LOGIN====>: success
```